# Can I draw pi on an android canvas to look like it was drawn with drawText?

Tags: android, canvas, drawtext

Hi I have an android canvas that I draw text on with a shadow layer and some other text effects.  I would like to be able to also draw π onto the canvas to look the same as drawText, but I dont think drawText supports UTF-8 so this is where I am stuck.  Does anyone know some other way I can accomplish this?  Making my own paths to display would work but I do not know how to make a nice looking pi path.  Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base on android documentation about [String](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html)

> A String is represented by array of UTF-16 values, such that Unicode supplementary characters (code points) are stored/encoded as surrogate pairs via Unicode code units (char).

Therefore, you can draw any unicode text in `Canvas`.

Comment: Ahh wow it worked perfectly.  Thanks very much, I tried using the pi character but for some reason got an invalid apk so i assumed it was that, thanks!